# Add tag 'Galileo'

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

As the Galileo GPS is now approaching full service status, can we create the tag 'Galileo' and add it to the following questions:

[Android devices and apps with support for Galileo positioning?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174225/android-devices-and-apps-with-support-for-galileo-positioning)

[Is there an industry-standard official mapping of Galileo satellites to global "PRN”/ID values?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163912/is-there-an-industry-standard-official-mapping-of-galileo-satellites-to-global)

etc.

Answer (score 4):

I have created the [galileo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galileo) tag and have added it to your questions.